# Taking different CSV variable in JMeter Loop

Tags: jmeter

I'm new in J-meter maybe what I ask it's easy but this is what i want to do.

First I got users in format user.namer.xN  meaning user.namex1, user.namer.x2 and so on.
I want to do the following each user to send 50 reqeusts and after every 50 request(after each users request) one request to url which contains link for DB restore handler. In the 50 requests that every user sends there is one different number that I want to read from CSV file. I want to end the test when I send 1500 reqests. So the test I wonder would look something like this..

counter  1 to 30

thread group 30  1  1

```
    loop 50
    csv (varibale name  ID)
    requests -------- How can I make on every loop to take other CSV variable
    end of loop
request to the handler
```

Any help

Comment: Hi, take a look at the example in %JMETER_HOME%\bin\examples. It is clear enough to understand

Answer (score 0):

the CSV data set config reads each line when staring each thread.
This is explained here:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

So you cannot use it the way you want. I can see two solutions:

1- you map each iteration of the loop on a thread. Each time you get a line holding users information. You will end in a thread group with 1500 iterations.

2- you should consider CSVread, which is a little bit more complex, but it allows you to control when to read the next line. Reference [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead).